# Sending map boundary via Jquery to google maps ui

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use this script to get the markers for Google Maps with JSON.
It is not working because I need to receive the boundary in the Json script like this:

```
$swLat=$_GET["swLat"];
$swLon=$_GET["swLon"];

$neLat=$_GET["neLat"];
$neLon=$_GET["neLon"];
```

That is where I need your help.

Google maps script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://skiweather.eu/gmap3/js/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var map = null;
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));
        var markers = new Array();

        var bounds = map.getBounds();
        var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();           


     $(function() { 

    demo.add(function() {

    $('#map').gmap().bind('init', function() { 
        $.getJSON( 'http://skiweather.eu/gmap3/markers/index.php', {zoom: zoomLevel, 
            swLat: bounds.getSouthWest().lat(), swLon: bounds.getSouthWest().lng(), 
            neLat: bounds.getNorthEast().lat(), neLon: bounds.getNorthEast().lng()}, function(data) { 
            $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {
                $('#map').gmap('addMarker', { 
                    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude), 
                    'bounds': true 
                }).click(function() {
                    $('#map').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': marker.content }, this);
                });
            });
        });
    });

    }).load();


    }); 


                    </script>

                </head>
                <body>
                <div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery/gmap-part of your code will not be executed at all.

Fixed code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() { 
    $('#map').gmap().bind('init', function() {
      var markers = new Array();
      var bounds = $(this).gmap('get','map').getBounds();
      var zoomLevel = $(this).gmap('get','map').getZoom();   
        $.getJSON( 'http://skiweather.eu/gmap3/markers/index.php', {zoom: zoomLevel, 
            swLat: bounds.getSouthWest().lat(), swLon: bounds.getSouthWest().lng(), 
            neLat: bounds.getNorthEast().lat(), neLon: bounds.getNorthEast().lng()}, function(data) { 
            $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {
                $('#map').gmap('addMarker', { 
                    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude), 
                    'bounds': true 
                }).click(function() {
                    $('#map').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': marker.content }, this);
                });
            });
        });
    });


    });
</script>
```

However, it's sending the data now, but it's still not working, because the server will not give any response(are you sure that there is a webservice that returns JSON-data?)

Comment: The returned JSON is not valid, use your console.

Comment: the thing is it should focus on Austria